# How to get an access token using the latest (alpha) version of FreshBooks API

Tags: php, freshbooks-api

I want to get an access token. I used the following code which is the same as in the documentation of the latest version of FreshBooks but it gives me an error.

```
if(!empty($_GET['code']) && isset($_GET['code']))
{
    $code=$_GET['code'];
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.freshbooks.com/auth/oauth/token",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING  => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT   => 30,

        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
            "grant_type"    => "authorization_code",
            "client_secret" => "xxxxxxxx",
            "code"          => $_GET['code'],
            "client_id"     => " xxxxxxx",
            "redirect_uri"  => "https://localhost/test2.php"
        ),
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "api-version: alpha",
            "cache-control: no-cache",
            "content-type: application/json",
            "postman-token: 471a0741-8466-2e3f-0006-8b9c3794ef9d"
        ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
        echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
        echo $response;
    }
}
```

It gives me the following response:

> 400 error invalid request param.

Any solutions?

Comment: This seems to suggest there is some problem in the structure of your request. Could you please post the link to the relevant section of the documentation for the API?

Comment: Or if you've already managed to fix this by yourself, feel free to post an answer to your own question so that other people may benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have generated this php snippet using postman ,you can refer my code

```
public function fobOath($code)
{
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.freshbooks.com/auth/oauth/token",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "grant_type=authorization_code&client_secret=<your_client_secret>&code=<your_code>&client_id=<your_client_id>&redirect_uri=<your_callback_address>",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "api-version: alpha",
            "cache-control: no-cache",
            "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
        echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
        echo $response;
    }

}
```

Comment: For payloads you could use raw (JSON).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I have resolved it after escaping the JSON string.

> Try This

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.freshbooks.com/auth/oauth/token",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\n    \"grant_type\": \"authorization_code\",\n    \"client_secret\": \"Your client secret\",\n    \"code\": \"your code\",\n    \"client_id\": \"your client id\",\n    \"redirect_uri\": \"https://www.yoururl.com/redirect\"\n}",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "api-version: alpha",
        "cache-control: no-cache",
        "content-type: application/json"
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    echo $response;
}
```